# MailMerge: From Excel to Word C#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I'm currently facing a problem regarding the MailMerge functionality of MS Word.

I had to rewrite an old VBA Application into C#. I'm practically done with that. New Application works fine. 
Except for one PopUp that I cannot get rid of. 
[image]

So I have been looking around on the web for the past 2 days because our clients don't want that pop up as it hasn't been there in the old application. 
However I couldn't find a proper solution for this. Except a few people mentioning that probably the Connection string is incorrect. But I found no resources telling me how it should look in the C# code

This it how it looks in the old application:

```
Word.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=strSourceDoc, ConfirmConversions:=False, _
        ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", _
        PasswordTemplate:="", WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", _
        Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:= _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & strSourceDoc & ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";" _
        , SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Tabelle1$`", SQLStatement1:="", SubType:= _
        wdMergeSubTypeAccess
```

I obviously tried already to take that connection key and use it in my code. But it does not prevent that pop up. I also tried playing around with the subtype. But it either doesn't change anything or throws a format exception.

This is whats working in C#:

```
mailApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(processedPath + file, true, false, true, 
    true, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, 
   "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=" + 
    processedPath + file + ";Mode=Read;", 
   "SELECT * FROM 'Tabelle1$'", 
   ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
   Word.WdMergeSubType.wdMergeSubTypeAccess);
```

How can I change the connection string to prevent that popup from showing?

Comment: Could "Tabelle1$" <> "Sheet1$" the problem? Word cannot find Tabelle1$ so it prompts for sheet selection.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm from Germany so we're running Excel with the German language pack. The Excel Sheets are named "Tabelle" here. So I believe that's fine. (It also prompts to select "Tabelle1$" in the popup for me)

Comment: Well, the image you posted is misleading then.

Comment: You should upload images directly to your Question so that we can include them in the question. People shouldn't have to click to an outside source to view pertinent information.

Comment: The popup appears when the connection information is insufficient for Word to identify the source. Why do you set `ConfirmConversions=true` in the C# code, when it's false in the VBA code? That can definitely cause prompts, although I don't know whether it's the case, here. You might also try passing `wdOpenFormatAuto` instead of `ref missing`, since that's also in the VBA code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that I could actually add picuters in here. Thanks for letting me know. I tried changing the confirmConversion attribute. As I said I already tried completely translating the VBA Code, but that didn't give me a working result. It throws an interop.com exception. Anyways. Tried again adding wdOpenFormatAuto. Still no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution, that is somehow working.

The actual problem (at least from what I tested) is the file extension not the connection string. I was using .xlsx files, as my source documents. But as soon as I tested with some xls Files the popup disapeared.

*I just took a "google session" to find out the differences between xls and xlsx.*

So I could change my code to work with xls Files only. Issue solved. But still an unpleasing solution for me tbh.

If you'd like to test around a little to maybe get it working with xlsx. Here is some code to test with (just bind it on a button click in winforms or something)

```
 class PerformMailMerge
    {
        Word.Application mailApp;
        Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Object oFalse = false;
        string _path = @"Your Path to Excel File";
        string savePath = @"Your Path to Word Document";

        public void mailMerge2()
        {
            mailApp = new Word.Application();
            mailApp.Visible = false;

            mailApp.Documents.Add();

            mailApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = Word.WdMailMergeMainDocType.wdMailingLabels;

            //OpenDataSource: 
            mailApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(_path,
                Word.WdOpenFormat.wdOpenFormatAllWordTemplates, true, true, true,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, "TABLE Tabelle1$", "SELECT * FROM `Tabelle1$",
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                Word.WdMergeSubType.wdMergeSubTypeWord2000);

            mailApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(savePath);
            mailApp.ActiveDocument.Close();
            mailApp.Quit();
        }    
    }
```

**EDIT:** 
So in case anyone will stumble upon this again. I found a solution to the problem. The solution is NOT specifying a WdMergeSubType. This allows reading from xlsx files and still doesn't show the popup!