# How can I use the mail merge step by step wizard in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word

I already have a Word document with the template and database, all fields are there, I just want to filter by "ID1" to create the letters and save them in .pdf

I am filtering them because I need the .pdf file for different sections with different names, so I want to automate the multiple filter "from ID1=x to ID1=y"  and save the .pdf file for each section

I'm using Visual Studio C#

Here is my code where I just open the word template:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace MailMerge
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            var document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

            document = application.Documents.Add(Template: @"C:/docPath.docx");
            application.Visible = true;

            Console.Write("Press Enter");
            Console.ReadLine();

            document.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[Mail merge step by step wizard IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kornu.png)

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. If you have a particular issue after [researching](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) existing answers, please [edit] your post to share some background info and a **[mcve] of your code** and relevant data. More tips here: *"[ask]"* and in the [help/on-topic], as well as this [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the sites' top user. Also please take the time to crop your screenshot.Good luck!

Comment: There's not really enough information here to provide you with an answer. Try recording a macro as you perform the steps in the UI you want to use. That will give you the objects, properties and methods - it will be VBA, but that will at least provide a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do this the way you propose; instead, you supply the filters as part of the SQLStatement parameter of the MailMerge.OpenDataSource method. If you manually configure a mailmerge main document with all the required parameters, the following Word macro will tell you what you need to incorporate into your code:

```
Sub MMTest()
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
  If .MainDocumentType <> wdNotAMergeDocument Then
    MsgBox "Mail Merge Data Source Name:" & vbCr & .DataSource.Name
    MsgBox "Mail Merge Connect String:" & vbCr & .DataSource.ConnectString
    MsgBox "Mail Merge Query String:" & vbCr & .DataSource.QueryString
  Else
    MsgBox "Not A Merge Document"
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i have a problem, the document i have returns as a wdNotAMergeDocument, what is the problem or how do i create a margedDocumentType

Here is my code in c#:  

    `var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    var document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
    document = application.Documents.Add(Template: @"C:/docPath.docx");
    var app = application.ActiveDocument.MailMerge;
    if (app.MainDocumentType != WdMailMergeMainDocType.wdNotAMergeDocument){}`  
  
    Sorry for the format im new here

Comment: If you're doing a mailmerge and the document you're using isn't already saved as a mailmerge main document, or you're suppressing the SQL message, you need to tell Word to configure the document for a mailmerge. There's plenty of C# code for that here that you can adapt to your needs (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736240/mailmerge-from-excel-to-word-c-sharp).